# Annoying persistant $_GET variables

Tags: php

I have an `<a href>` in my webpage that has the following link:

`<a href=\"?remove=0\">Remove</a>`

Which is fine.  I then reference it by the following:

`if(isset($_REQUEST['remove']))`

To check if it was set and then perform the relative actions (removing the value from array).

BUT, when I click ANOTHER form in my php page, which is set to `method='POST'`, The `$_GET` value stays in the URL bar and so therefore for some reason is passed **again** and is ruining my program.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you generating the URL for the second form in your page?

Comment: oh, Im not, i simply have `<form method="POST">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing an `action=` prop in your form. If you don't specify where the form should post to, it posts to the current URL, query string included.

Posts to current URL:

```
<form method="post">
```

Posts to URL you specify:

```
<form method="post" action="mypage.php">
```

Comment: I.. Did not know this.  It's the first time i've really left out the action part so.

Comment: i will! theres a time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Removing sounds like a dangerous operation. It shouldn't be performed in response to a GET request: a user might reload the page, accidentally removing something again, or a searching robot might follow that link and remove that something (assuming, of course, it has permissions to). Even browsers nowadays do prefetching - what happens if one of the prefetched links is the remove link?

So, it would be wise to check

```
if (isset($_POST['remove']))
```

and convert the link to remove to a form.